# HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found - JSON Spring MVC

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, json, spring

I write 1 webapp,i try to send 1 JSON to server and save it into MySQL. I've got this problem:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/jsonspringhibernateexample/addclass [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 910ms]
```

This is my controller (use to add one Class to Mysql):

```
@Controller
public class ClassController {

    @Autowired
    private ClassService classService;
    @RequestMapping(value ="/index",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getIndex(ModelMap map){
        map.put("listClass",classService.getListClass());
        map.put("studentClass", new Class());
        return "class";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value ="/addclass", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addClass(@RequestBody Class studentClass){
        classService.addClass(studentClass);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

This is my jquery to call controller:

```
$("#addclass").click(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url:"addclass",
        type: "post",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({className:$("#input").val(),listStudent:null}),
    }).done(function(){
        $("#listclass").appent("<option>"+$("#input").val()+"</option>");
    });
});
```

When i click "#addclass" button, the class was added but controller not return index.jsp, and i got my trouble.
Why do i get that error? and how can i solve it?
Thanks!

Comment: Is your controller actually getting loaded? make a constructor and add a println to see if gets called

Comment: Ya, controller received the request, println worked.

Comment: I've solved this problem by add @ResponseBody before controller, but i still don't understand why it's working?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `@RequestMapping(value="/jsonspringhibernateexample")` before your controler class ?
Else try to remove `headers = {"Content-type=application/json"}`, maybe the content-type is wrong (but I'm not sure).

Comment: i removed headers = {"Content-type=application/json"}, but same error! when i add 1 class, this controller run ok, the class was added, but then ajax run error function(i think, error [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 910ms] make ajax return error function). I see that error at browser console
Sorry my english's not good. Hope you understand!

Comment: My english is not better, can you show the entire controller class?

Comment: The service is not enough, you need a controller, and you need to handle the route /jsonspringhibernateexample/addclass. Where do you handle the first part: /jsonspringhibernateexample?

Comment: /jsonspringhibernateexample this is my webapp url!!

Comment: There is a basic missing, I did the test: I put your controller, I bound this a JSP file (with some JSON test content) to the "index" view in my common-definition.xml and it worked.

Comment: I've solved this problem by add @ResponseBody before controller, but i still don't understand why it's working?